# column width in \pgfplotstabletranspose with comma as decimal spearator

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to plot data from a .dat file which is called `Analysis.dat` and looks like this:

```
number   $Test1$   $Test2$   $Test3$
1   121.14   117.92   122.67
2   121.29   117.40   121.16
3   121.66   116.49   120.90
4   119.59   112.66   118.60
5   116.10   109.19   114.48
6   110.34   108.63   106.26
```

The current plot in LaTeX looks like this:
[image: This is the current plot]

Below the plot I'm trying to conceptualize a data table. Now I want to align the table columns perfectly below the plot, so the "numbers" (1,2,3,4,5,6) in the table are directly below the numbers of the plot (e.g. number 1 is nearly perfectly aligned in the screenshot above).

While using a dot as a decimal separator I was able to modify the column width with " column type={p{1cm}}" e.g. But now, with a comma as decimal separator this doesn't work anymore and I get the error:

> ```
> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
> ```

Does anyone know how to solve this error? I would be thankful for every help!
This would be the code for the screenshot above:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen, border={59pt, 0pt, 0pt, 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x = 2.75cm,
    ticklabel style ={/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, 1000 sep = {}},
    xlabel=\large number ,
    ylabel=\large seconds ,
    title=\Large mean cycle time,
    xmin= 1,
    xmax= 6,
    xtick={1,2,...,6},
    ytick={106, 108, 110,...,124},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    grid = both,
    axis background/.style={fill=white!10}],
]
\addplot table [x={number}, y={$Test1$}]{Analysis.dat};
\addplot table[x={number}, y={$Test2$}]{Analysis.dat};
\addplot[mark = diamond*] table[x={number}, y={$Test3$}] {Analysis.dat};
\legend{$Test1$\\$Test2$\\$Test3$\\}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\noindent
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=number, input colnames to=number]\loadedtable{Analysis.dat}
\vspace{-3.5cm}
\hspace{-1.5cm}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[use comma, string type,every even row/.style={
before row={}},  
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule},
every column/.style={ column type={p{1.65cm}}},
columns/1/.style={dec sep align, zerofill},
columns/2/.style={dec sep align, zerofill},
columns/3/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
columns/4/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
columns/5/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
columns/6/.style={dec sep align,zerofill}]\loadedtable
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like the following? For that I didn't modify the table, but *stretched* and *moved* the plot. (I didn't want to "stretch" the table, because then there would be very much white-space which won't look very good I think.)

Fore more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    \begin{filecontents}{Analysis.dat}
        number   $Test1$   $Test2$   $Test3$
        1   121.14   117.92   122.67
        2   121.29   117.40   121.16
        3   121.66   116.49   120.90
        4   119.59   112.66   118.60
        5   116.10   109.19   114.48
        6   110.34   108.63   106.26
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % first plot the table in a node
        \node (table) {%
            \pgfplotstabletranspose[
                colnames from=number,
                input colnames to=number,
            ]\loadedtable{Analysis.dat}%
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                use comma,
                string type,
                every even row/.style={
                    before row={},
                },
                every head row/.style={
                    before row=\toprule,
                    after row=\midrule,
                },
                every last row/.style={
                    after row=\bottomrule,
                },
                every column/.style={
                    column type={p{1.65cm}},
                },
                columns/1/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
                columns/2/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
                columns/3/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
                columns/4/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
                columns/5/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
                columns/6/.style={dec sep align,zerofill},
            ]{\loadedtable}
        };
        % then create a dummy coordinate above the table where the diagram
        % will be plotted
        % (for the vertical shift adapt the `yshift' and for aligning the
        %  "x" numbers of the table and plot adapt the `xshift')
        \coordinate (above table) at
            ([yshift=2ex,xshift=2.6ex] table.north);

        \begin{axis}[
            % position the plot at the previously created dummy coordinate
            % and set the anchor accordingly
            at={(above table)},
            anchor=outer south,
            % adjust `x' (or alternatively `width') to find the right
            % "stretching" of the plot
            x=14mm,
            ticklabel style ={
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    use comma,
                    1000 sep={},
            },
            xlabel=\large number ,
            ylabel=\large seconds ,
            title=\Large mean cycle time,
            legend pos=north east,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            grid=both,
        ]
            \addplot                 table [x={number},y={$Test1$}] {Analysis.dat};
            \addplot                 table [x={number},y={$Test2$}] {Analysis.dat};
            \addplot [mark=diamond*] table [x={number},y={$Test3$}] {Analysis.dat};

            \legend{$Test1$,$Test2$,$Test3$}

%            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
%            % for debugging purposes
%            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,6} {
%                \coordinate (x#1) at (axis cs:#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});
%            }
%            % -----------------------------------------------------------------

        \end{axis}

%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % for debugging purposes
%        \foreach \i in {1,...,6} {
%            \draw [help lines] (x\i) |- (table.south);
%        }
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Wonderful. I slightly shrinked the scale of the y-Axis and I exactly obtained what I wanted! Before uploading this problem I caused an error with plotting the table and the standalone packages, so I had to use `varwidth=\maxdimen, border={59pt, 0pt, 0pt, 0pt}` as an argument. You even found a more sophisticated solution for that problem! Thank you!